# Export/Import data in MySQL using MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, import, export

I am trying to take the back-up of database using  MySql workbench and restore it into an identical db on other server.I can see the following ways of doing it -

1.Export entire schema and import it in the identical destination database

In this case while restoring it to the identical destination db...will it overwrite the existing tables data or will it be doing a truncate and insert in them?
Also, I observed that if the data export/import is interrupted by any chance it gets corrupted and few of the tables are restored.In this case it becomes difficult to identify which table(S) are restored exactly.

2.Table by table export and import

Which option is best suitable option out of the above two?Do we have any other option of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Mysql workbench, you might simply run a DB back up extract, for example:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --opt --host=$dbhost --user=$dbuser --password=$dbpass $dbname > $dumpfile
```

(I run this via php on a host server using the passthru command), it sounded from your question that you wanted to retain the data and this would do that.
This can then be run against an empty database (it will drop tables & recreate them if they exist but I find it cleaner to delete and recreate an empty database first) - hey presto duplicate.